# Recorrer directorio de forma recursiva

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy realizando un programa creando, modificando y recorriendo `directorios` y `archivos`, estoy atascado en la parte de mostrar en la pantalla el contenido de un `directorio` y en el caso de tener `sub-directorios` mostrar lo que estos tienen.

Código que uso para mostrar lo que hay dentro de un `directorio`.

```
public static void caso6() {
    System.out.println("Indica la ruta del direcotrio: ");
    String ruta = keyboard.nextLine();
    File rutaArchivo = new File(ruta);

    if (rutaArchivo.exists()) {
        String[] archivos = rutaArchivo.list();

        if (archivos == null) {
            System.out.println("No hay ficheros en el directorio especificado");
        } else {
            for (int x = 0; x < archivos.length; x++) {
                System.out.println(archivos[x]);

            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("El directori o la ruta no existen.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuál es el problema exactamente?

Comment: que no se como hacerlo para que muestre el contenido de los sub-directorio usando un método recursivo, esto solo muestra el contenido del directotrio indicado

Comment: Podrías usar los directorios que se almacenan en la variable `archivos` para crear otro bucle que hiciera lo mismo. Es decir, en un void almacenas la funcion de repasar los archivos de un directorio, el parámetro que le pasas es el directorio del que quieras ver sus archivos, y asi lo puedes ir usando todas las veces que necesites hasta que tengas todos los archivos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los resuelves con un método recursivo. (Ejemplo en c#)

```
    public static void PrintFilesInDir(string path)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            foreach (var item in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(item);
                PrintFilesInDir(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Un ejemplo bastante completo lo tienes al contar los directorios a partir de la posición actual donde se ejecuta tu programa, la clave está en la función Walkin() que es recursiva con el objetivo de recorrer todo el árbol de directorios:

```
public class CountDirectories {
    private static int numDir;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            numDir = 0;
            walkin(new File(".\\")); // Directorio raíz, modificar para pruebas..
            System.out.println("\nSe han encontrado: " + numDir + " directorios");
            File salida = new File(".\\salida.txt");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(salida));
            bw.write("Se han encontrado: " + numDir + " directorios \n");
            bw.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void walkin(File dir) {

        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                if (listFile[i].isDirectory())
                    walkin(listFile[i]);
            }
        } else {
            numDir++;
            System.out.print(numDir + ", "); // Por Debug, pare ver los directorios que va encontrando.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void cas7() {
    System.out.println("Indica la ruta del direcotri: ");
    String ruta = keyboard.nextLine();

    listFiles(ruta);
}

public static void listFiles(String ruta) {
    File rutaArx = new File(ruta);

    if (rutaArx.exists()) {
        File[] arxius = rutaArx.listFiles();

        if (arxius == null) {
            System.out.println("No hi ha fitxers en el directori que has indicat");
        } else {
            for (int x = 0; x < arxius.length; x++) {
                if (arxius[x].isFile()) {
                    System.out.println(arxius[x]);
                } else if (arxius[x].isDirectory()) {
                    listFiles(arxius[x].getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("El directori o la ruta no existeixen.");
    }
}
```

muchas gracias! este es el código que he usado al final por si le es de ayuda a alguien